# I'm trying to copy database from sqlite3 to postgresql by using sequel that is database toolkit,but I encountered an error

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlite, sequel

I have a site that consisted of Django that is python web framework,and I use sqlite3 for that site.

I want to move sqlite3 postgresql because of that sqlite3 frequently cause error.

So I find sequel that is tool and can copy database even between different porduct of database.

here is command.

```
sequel -C sqlite://db.sqlite3 config/database.yml
```

- db.sqlite3 : source of database
- database.yml : the settings of dst of database

the content of database.yml is here.password is removed.

```
development:
    adapter: postgres
    encoding: utf8
    charset: utf8
    database: erogazou_site
    pool: 5
    username: erogazou_site
    password:
    host: localhost
test:
    adapter: postgres
    encoding: utf8
    charset: utf8
    database: erogazou_site
    pool: 5
    username: erogazou_site
    password:
    host: localhost

production:
    adapter: postgres
    encoding: utf8
    charset: utf8
    database: erogazou_site
    pool: 5
    username: erogazou_site
    password:
    host: localhost
```

And here is error.

```
Error: Sequel::DatabaseError: PG::StringDataRightTruncation: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(64)
```

I know the error says that the length of data is too long for its type,and I think the error occurs becaouse of that the type of data change during sequel convert it for between different product of database.

sequel github : https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel

I want to copy the data of sqlite3 into postgresql.

How do I do this?

Comment: [SQLite ignores column data types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so if you have `varchar(64)` in your SQLite schema it's entirely possible for there to be values larger than 64 characters. PostgreSQL does not ignore its data types. You'll have to verify the values in SQLite actually match their data types. ***Or*** get rid of the limits and change your `varchar(x)` to `text`; I recommend this as limits on text fields are often arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you for your asnswer.

I think too that I want to use `text` type for text field in PostgreSQL.

But the type of field of PostgreSQL is decided automacally by sequel,so I don't know how to change the type of field when copying database.

I suppose sequel convert `text` type of sqlite to `varchar` of postgresql because the error says about varchar.

Comment: Could you show us the SQLite schema for the table which is having a problem?